# PHP send different email to different recipients using SMTP

Tags: php, email, smtp

I am having trouble figuring out how to send an email to recipient1 with their information, then an email to recipient2 with their information, recipient3 with their information, and so on, all within the same script.

```
$date=date("Y-m-d");
$time=date("H:i");
$result=mysql_query("select * from reminder where R_Date='$date' && R_Time='$time'");
date_default_timezone_set( "Asia/Kuala_Lumpur");
$receiver=array();
$mail = new PHPMailer;
//$mail->SMTPDebug = 3;                               // Enable verbose debug output

$mail->isSMTP();                                      // Set mailer to use SMTP
$mail->Host = 'smtp.gmail.com';  // Specify main and backup SMTP servers
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;                               // Enable SMTP authentication
$mail->Username = 'example@gmail.com';                 // SMTP username
$mail->Password = 'password';                           // SMTP password
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl';                            // Enable TLS encryption, `ssl` also accepted
$mail->Port = 465;                                    // TCP port to connect to

while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
if($row){
    $mail->From = 'from@example.com';
    $mail->FromName = 'CIMB Clicks';
    $mail->addAddress($row['R_Email'], $row['R_ID']);     // Add a recipient
    $mail->addAddress($row['R_Email']);               // Name is optional
    $mail->WordWrap = 1000;                                 // Set word wrap to 50 characters
    $mail->isHTML(true);                                  // Set email format to HTML
    $body="Greetings from Clicks!<br><br>".

        $row['R_Title'].".<br>".
        "This is My Reminder from Clicks regarding ".$row['R_Title'].".<br><br>".

        "Thank you & have a good day ahead!<br><br>


    $mail->Subject = 'My Reminder from Clicks';
    $mail->Body    = $body;
    $mail->AltBody = 'This is the body in plain text for non-HTML mail clients';

}
}
```

my Database

```
R_ID  R_Title      R_Date       R_Time   R_Email
 1     Top Up    2014/10/15     19:41    email@hotmail.com
 2    Transfer   2014/10/15     19:41    email@live.com
```

Comment: Could you futher elaborate? It's next to impossible to guess what your problem really is. Do you have some examples? How does the e-mail look for different recipients? Can you post some code that handles the e-mail sending?

Comment: the problem is the $row['R_Title'] which remain the same content once i send to the recipients. I wanna get the different content from the database.

Comment: Do all e-mail have $row['R_Title'] in the text, or do they all have the same text as one of the values in the database for R_Title?

Comment: All email have $row['R_Title'].

Comment: Put echo() arround the places where you try to append data from the database?

Comment: which will auto send the email to the recipients once the date and time is reached. But when the R_Date and R_Time is repeated there will only send the "transfer" to email@hotmail.com and email@live.com. But the email@hotmail.com supposed to "Top Up". How I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have an array of E-Mail address you could make a foreach-loop. But your question isnt that detailed.

```
$recipients = array('peter@anymail.com', 'paul@anymail.com', 'mary@anymail.com');
$content = 'same content';
$subject = 'same subject';

foreach($recipients as $address) {
    mail($address, $subject, $content, 'FROM: me@anymail.com');
}
```

Comment: nope. Actually my question is about the content. I cant send the exactly content to the recipients.